# Composite datawindow get Clicked Row

Tags: powerbuilder, composite, datawindow

I have a composite datawindow in which the nested datawindow is a label type datawindow. I have created a userobject using this composite datawindow.

In the double click event of the datawindow I want to be able to find out the Clicked row of the nested datawindow. But every time I double click I get the row variable as 1 and GetRow() as 0.

I am doing the following:

```
datawindowChild idw_child 

idw_compsite.GetChild('dw_child', idw_child) 
idw_child.SetTransObject(SQLCA) 
idw_child.GetRow() //This Returns 0

//Another Try
//This Returns Band as well as row# with a tabbed separator 
//however from 2nd page the row# returns as 0.
String ls_band_row

ls_band_row = idw_Child.GetBandAtPointer()
```

Comment: Do not post links to questions outside of SO. Post all the relevant information in your question. Do not expect SO users to connect somewhere else to get the missing informations.

Comment: OK here is the full question :
I have a composite datawindow in which the nested datawindow is a label datawindow. I have created a userobject using this composite datawindow. 
On the doubleclick event of the datawindow i want to be able to find out the Clicked row of the nested dw . however everytime i double click i get row variable as 1 and GetRow() as 0. 
i have done like below. 
datawindowChild idw_child 
idw_compsite.GetChild('dw_child', idw_child) 
idw_child.SetTransObject.SQLCA() 

I have used GetBandAtpointer() which works for 2 pages however from 3rd page i get 0 as row number

Comment: Could you edit your question in order to put this information directly inside it? It is difficult to figure it from the comment. The text layout is terrible.